# Salvar lista em arquivo csv sem o index com pandas

Tags: python, lista, pandas, csv

estou tentando salvar uma lista em um arquivo csv no formato append mas meu código salva o index também. O arquivo csv que quero obter é:

```
id,setor,texto,responsavel,ano,trimestre
1,diretoria,aumentar faturamento,diretor,2022,3
```

sendo que o cabeçalho já está salvo no arquivo previamente. E pra isso estou usando o código:

```
id_objetivo += 1    
setor = input("Qual o seu setor? ")
texto = input("Qual o seu objetivo? ")
responsavel = input("Quem é responsável? ")
ano = int(input("Qual o ano de vigência do objetivo? "))
ciclo = int(input("Qual o trimestre? ")

objetivo = [id_objetivo, setor, texto, responsavel, ano, ciclo]
salvar = pandas.DataFrame(objetivo)
salvar.T.to_csv('objfile.csv', mode='a')
```

e estou obtendo o resultado:

```
   id,setor,texto,responsavel,ano,ciclo,0,1,2,3,4,5
0,1,diretoria,aumentar faturamento, diretor,2022,3
```

Como posso corrigir?

Answer (score -2):

Achei a resposta pela documentação, apenas utilizando os parâmetros `index = false` e `header = false` em `to_csv()`